# jquery not parsing ajax result

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, http-headers

In order to fix a problem with an ajax request not working in IE, I changed my code. Now it's not working in any browser. The weird part is, that ajax request does gets a proper result. Only this result is not parsed. How to fix this? Do I need to change some headers or so?

all functions are methods in the tbGeocoder object.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'false',
        jsonpCallback: 'json_callback' + tbGeocoder.requestIndex,
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            q: input,
            limit: 1,
            json_calback: 'json_callback' + tbGeocoder.requestIndex
        },
        beforeSend: function(x) { 
            if (x && x.overrideMimeType) { 
                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
            } 
        },
        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(type);
          /*for (key in data) {
                //console.log(key);
            }*/
            return data;
        },
        success: tbGeocoder.processRequestResult,

        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
    tbGeocoder.requestIndex++;
},
preProcessRequestResult: function (data, type) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(type);
    for (key in data) {
        //console.log(key);
    }
    return data;
},
processRequestResult: function (data) {
    console.log('==>in loop for nominatim');
}
```

in firebug the console output for a input like input="Den Dolechh"
is as follows:

```
code address location
Den Dolech
undefined
jsonp
parsererror
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}
```

In the network status you can see the headers are like:

```
 Replyheaders
 Access-Control-Allow-Orig...   *
 Connection close
 Content-Length 445
 Content-Location   search.php
 Content-Type   application/json; charset=UTF-8
 Date   Thu, 05 Jul 2012 10:31:11 GMT
 Server Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
 TCN    choice
 Vary   negotiate
 X-Powered-By   PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17

 Requestheaders
 Accept */*
 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language    nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
 Connection keep-alive
 Host   nominatim.openstreetmap.org
 Referer    http://localhost/locations/add
 User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
```

and the reply is:

```
 [{"place_id":"44757488","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"36859933","boundingbox":["51.4484252929688","51.449333190918","5.48478031158447","5.48527336120605"],"lat":"51.4489435225293","lon":"5.48514453068994","display_name":"Den Dolech, Eindhoven, Samenwerkingsverband Regio Eindhoven, Noord-Brabant, 5600 MB, Nederland","class":"highway","type":"residential"}]
```

How do I fix this? I get the data, but how do I get it out?

Comment: on 'success' try to pass into: tbGeocoder.processRequestResult the data,type so it will be able to work on it inside this function.

Comment: the problem is that the success function is never reached, since the ajax decides there's a parsing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is very annoying. The answer is a fix for a Typo!

the line

```
 json_calback: 'json_callback' + tbGeocoder.requestIndex
```

should be

```
data: {
            format: 'json',
            q: input,
            addressdetails: 1,
            limit: 1,
            json_callback: 'json_callback' + tbGeocoder.requestIndex
        },
```

Notice the double ´l´ in callback. I also added the addressdetails because that is what I was looking for anyway ;-)

with that I get a proper jsonp resonse:

```
 json_callback11([{"place_id":"44757488","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"36859933","boundingbox":["51.4484252929688","51.449333190918","5.48478031158447","5.48527336120605"],"lat":"51.4489435225293","lon":"5.48514453068994","display_name":"Den Dolech, Eindhoven, Samenwerkingsverband Regio Eindhoven, Noord-Brabant, 5600 MB, Nederland","class":"highway","type":"residential","address":{"road":"Den Dolech","residential":"Eindhoven","suburb":"Eindhoven","city":"Eindhoven","county":"Samenwerkingsverband Regio Eindhoven","state":"Noord-Brabant","postcode":"5600 MB","country":"Nederland","country_code":"nl"}}])
```

which is processed correctly.
This is a need trick (to make the json_callback and the jsonp_callback the same...) to fix the same origin problem and differences between browsers. This works in IE9, FF and Chrome on Windows and FF, Chrome and Safiri on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use data directly in `processRequestResult`

use `data.d` and store it in some variable.

```
var tempData = data.d;
```

now use `tempData` instead of `data`.

Comment: I don´t understand this. Due to the parseerror, the success function isn´t even reached. And even so, data is ´undefined´, so how can data.d have any content?

Answer (score 0):

Your attached JSON is valid JSON, **not JSONP**.

```
// Some valid JSON responses:
// (even yours is valid JSON)
{x: 1}
[{x: 1}, {x: 2}]

// Some valid JSONP responses:
foo({x: 1})
bar([{x: 1}, {x: 2}])
```

Comment: This seems to be the problem, but how to solve it? I need the jsonp request to make sure I also get a response in IE (which I won´t get otherwise due to the same origin issue). I need to trick the ajax to accept the incomming json object, now it seems like it is only accepting jsonp.

Comment: You have to modify your server code or use JSON and call manually the callback.